# SQL pull two records if one is selected in the drop down

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I have a form where the user has to select a country from a drop down and then results of that country is displayed on next page.  England is intentionally hidden in the form. However, if United Kingdom is selected, I need to display both United Kingdom and England's results on the next page (combined results so user doesn't know there is a difference in countries.  Here's my pseudo SQL query

```
select DISTINCT country_id, country, language, abbreviation
from countries
where country_id = :country_id
```

I know I have to use a `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause to check if United Kingdom is selected then include England. But I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Do England and Great Britain have same or different country_id's?

Comment: Please show sample data and output.  I doubt that England/UK is the only edge case in your table.

Comment: If it's a country in a country, shouldn't there be a subcountryID?

Answer (score 0):

```
where (country_id = :country_id or (country_id = <UK> and country_id = <ENGLAND>))
```

Parens really aren't necessary here but many people forget them when AND and OR come into play so I just wrapped that part of the logic so you can add further filters on the end of that.

And assuming that your `country_id`s are unique you shouldn't really need that `DISTINCT` in your query.

If you really like `case` expressions then this would be equivalent although there's nothing special about it. I'm not sure the first one will give you a better plan but I think this second one is more likely to be worse.

```
where
    case
        when :country_id = <UK> and country_id = <ENGLAND>
        then :country_id -- treat England as though it's UK
        else country_id
    end = :country_id
```

Comment: For clarity's sake, shouldn't there also be brackets around the `:country_id = <UK> and country_id = <ENGLAND>`? I.e. `where (country_id = :country_id or (:country_id = <UK> and country_id = <ENGLAND>))`

Comment: @Boneist I'll let you have that position but it's certainly not mine. I don't mind being explicit about some things yet by junior high we have all pretty much learned the convention that multiplication precedes addition. I'm from an older school of developers and I expect that people should know that AND and OR are parallels with the same precedence rule.

Comment: I know my BODMAS, but AND/OR precedence has never really stuck with me for whatever reason. It's just ironic, IMHO, that you specifically mentioned brackets, but then skipped some.

Comment: Yeah, I did indeed think about adding the extra pair. I guess it's one of those pet peeves of mine that's hard to get over. The difference being that one pair matters while the other doesn't.